# Why is json_decode producing NULL in this case?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have an array I've created like

```
[{
    "assetPreviewUrl":"pic1.jpg",
    "assetUrl":"pic2.jpg"
},
{
    "assetPreviewUrl":"pic3.jpg",
    "assetUrl":"pic4.jpg"
}]
```

and best `POST`ing I stringify it and place it as the value of

```
<input type="hidden" name="slideData" />
```

but as soon as I run

```
$slideData = json_decode($_POST['slideData']);
```

on the server side I find out through a test that `$slideData` is `null`.

I have verified

- that <`input type="hidden" name="slideData" />` has the correct `value` before the `form` is submitted (through `console.log($('input[name="slideData"]').val())`)
- that `$slideData`
- that `$_POST['slideData']` is not null (through `'Was $_POST[\'slideData\'] null ?' . (!$_POST['slideData'] ? 'yes' : 'no'`)

Any idea? Need more info?

Comment: Because you are _Not Douglas Crockford_. You know who discovered JSON, the same guy which you are not

Comment: @PaulCrovella It's valid indeed

Comment: So what does `$_POST['slideData']` actually contain? Use `var_dump` to make a debug output of that value.

Comment: @NotDouglasCrockford, are you putting array value into input hidden value place.?

Comment: Please add the Javascript you're using to put the JSON in to the hidden field.

Comment: Are you, for some reason, **not** setting `method="post"` to the actual form? `<form action="page.php" method="post"><!-- ... --><input type="hidden" name="slideData" /><input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Send the form" /></form>`... if it's correct, what's the output of `var_dump($_POST['slideData']); die;`? Did you un-stringify the variable before using `json_decode()`?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I thought that `json_decode` is called on strings http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. So why would I need to first "decode" it?

Comment: Yes, but when you say "stringify", I thought you were meaning "encoding" it for saving or transmitting it (like escaping characters or so). Did you actually echo the $_POST["slideData"] variable?

Comment: I've echoed it and noticed that it escapes the key names

Comment: Try this: `$slideData = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['slideData'] ) );`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are setting one value (slideData) to an array of json values. First, post the data as an array:

```
foreach ($slideData as $val)
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='slideData[]' value='$val' />";
```

Then try to decode the json of each of values of the array:

```
foreach ($_POST['slideData'] as $val)
    echo json_decode($val);
```